# how to eliminate invalid characters in text file while loading to sqlserve table using ssis?

Tags: ssis

I have text file in which some records contains invalid characteres like #,&,* in between words,now I have to remove all those characters and load th original word into table,
For Example:
Sam#som-->Samsom
Su&*se-->Suse

Answer (score 0):

You could probably accomplish what you want using a **Script Transformation** and Regular Expressions.

Here is a blog post on the topic: [Pattern matching in SSIS using Regular Expressions and the Script component](http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2011/07/pattern-matching-in-ssis-using-regular-expressions-and-the-script-component/)